# Blacked out textures

Tags: texturing

Can anybody tell me why my textures are showing up black?  I must have changed something because it wasnt always like this but I figure it out.[image]

Comment: in the Viewport Shading panel (top left of your 3D view) choose Studio instead of MatCap?

Comment: @moonboots any lighting setting should be able to show the texture. AFAIK it's either the color setting that is wrong, or the material itself.

Comment: Yes I missed that he specifically wanted to see his textures   ;)

Answer (score 1):

To see textures while in Solid shading:

In the *Viewport Shading* popover, make sure the Color setting is set to *Texture*:

[image]

- Only the last selected texture node is displayed
- Procedural textures are not supported and will show up as grey
- Color and Shader Mix nodes will show the last selected texture node too
- Any other node is ignored

[image: demo gif]

If you want a more accurate representation of your materials, you need to set your viewport shading to either Material or Rendered, but at the cost of performance:

[image: demo viewport shadings]